# Error when using projectRaster in R

Tags: raster, coordinate-system, r

I'm having a problem with projectRaster on a raster brick in WGS84 to a  projected coordinate system in R.

I have obtained some oceanographic data in netCDF format from the [Copernicus Marine Environmental Monitoring Service](http://marine.copernicus.eu/about-us/about-eu-copernicus/). An example of one of these netCDFs is [here](https://app.box.com/s/d7gz342tbothao90pr5esfou8l69mnh8).

The CRS (coordinate reference system) of the netCDFs is the WGS84 datum `(+proj=longlat +datum=WGS84 +ellps=WGS84 +towgs84=0,0,0)` and contains 75 depth layers for a single variable (in this case, salinity) for a single month in a single year (in this case, January 1993). I have trimmed the netCDF by both geographical extent and depth (an example of trimmed netCDF [here](https://app.box.com/s/uf3eyzy37994a5dmbtv8dzqaixkevf8p)).

I have loaded the trimmed netCDF into R as a raster brick using the following.

```
library("ncdf4")
ncbr <- brick("../data/env/CMEMS_GLOBAL_REANALYSIS_PHY_001_025_salinity_monthly_mean_1993-01.nclonlat.ncdepthtrim.nc")
ncbr
```

Which gives the following output

```
"level" set to 1 (there are 47 levels)class       : RasterBrick 
dimensions  : 97, 113, 10961, 1  (nrow, ncol, ncell, nlayers)
resolution  : 0.25, 0.25  (x, y)
extent      : -71.125, -42.875, 37.875, 62.125  (xmin, xmax, ymin, ymax)
coord. ref. : +proj=longlat +datum=WGS84 +ellps=WGS84 +towgs84=0,0,0 
data source : C:\Users\xxx\xxx\xxx\xxx\data\env\CMEMS_GLOBAL_REANALYSIS_PHY_001_025_salinity_monthly_mean_1993-01.nclonlat.ncdepthtrim.nc 
names       : X377316 
z-value     : 377316 
varname     : salinity 
level       : 1
```

The next step is to project the raster brick into the [Canada Albers Equal Area Conic](https://epsg.io/102001) projected coordinate system `(+proj=aea +lat_1=50 +lat_2=70 +lat_0=40 +lon_0=-96 +x_0=0 +y_0=0 +datum=NAD83 +units=m +no_defs)`. To do this I have used the following code:

```
canada_eq_ar_proj <- "+proj=aea +lat_1=50 +lat_2=70 +lat_0=40 +lon_0=-96 +x_0=0 +y_0=0 +ellps=GRS80 +datum=NAD83 +units=m +no_defs"
library("rgdal")
rp <- projectRaster(ncbr, crs = canada_eq_ar_proj)
```

Which throws me the following error:

```
Error in .readRowsNetCDF(x = x, row = row, nrows = nrows, col = col, ncols = ncols) : no slot of name "band" for this object of class ".MultipleRasterData"
```

On Google search I only found [one other person](https://stat.ethz.ch/pipermail/r-help/2018-May/454631.html) who seemed to have this error, but when trying to add a raster layer to a raster brick (so a different problem to mine).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After talking with Michael Sumner (who is based at the Australian Antarctic Division) it seems that the issue lies with the Raster package from which `project.Raster` is run from. It should be solved with the next update (no ETA), but in the meantime, Michael kindly provided a [DIY work-around](https://gist.github.com/mdsumner/77e6c9da08433022fa005c7399019dc8).

Answer (score 0):

I managed to project a test brick, but your data failed, as you say:

```
> rp <- projectRaster(ncbr, crs = canada_eq_ar_proj)
Error in .readRowsNetCDF(x = x, row = row, nrows = nrows, col = col, ncols = ncols) : 
  no slot of name "band" for this object of class ".MultipleRasterData"
```

but you can project the first (and only) layer:

```
> rp <- projectRaster(ncbr[[1]], crs = canada_eq_ar_proj)
>
```

if you have multiple layers you can probably project them all separately and bind them back into a brick if you need it.

Comment: Thanks Spacedman. It's throwing me a warning - "no non-missing arguments to min; returning Infno non-missing arguments to max; returning -Inf". 

Then when I check the resolution (the cell x, y) I get "15000, 23300". As it should have been projected into an equal area, I believe the resolution should have the same cell x, y

I also tried to change the ncbr[[1]] to ncbr[[3]] (which I assumed was how you access each layer), but it threw another error... "Error in .local(x, ...) : not a valid subset"

Comment: 1) I get no warnings. 2) projected extent & resolution is essentially arbitrary and `raster` makes a fair guess at a decent extent + resolution. There's no reason they should be square for an equal area projection. If you want them square then use the other parameters of `projectRaster`. 3) your NC file only reads in as one layer...